# Timeout exception using future.get()- Java ThreadPools

Tags: threadpool

I understand that `future.get()` is a blocking method. I have a simple class which submits tasks in a for loop, each task prints Name of the Thread.
When I use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and `future.get()` in a loop, as far as I understand each loop is a synchronous flow and there should be no scope of TimeOut exception.
But I notice this exception coming. Can someone suggest why this is happening.

The code is as follows:

```
public class AsynchronusExecutorTest {

private static ExecutorService executor = null;

static {
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    System.out.println("New executor");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        final Future<?> future = executor.submit(new MyRunnable3("Thread" + i));
        try {
            future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Thread returns");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Time out occured Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
}

class MyRunnable3 implements Runnable {
String name;

public MyRunnable3(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("This is test " + name);
    if (name.equals("Thread0")) {
        for (;;) {

        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code would never return `if (name.equals("Thread0"))`:

```
if (name.equals("Thread0")) {
    for (;;) {

    }
}
```

And you are passing "Thread0" when i == 0:

```
for (int i = 0;; i++) {
    final Future<?> future = executor.submit(new MyRunnable3("Thread" + i));
    //...
}
```

You might want change `for (int i = 0;; i++)` to `for (int i = 1;; i++)` .